# How to Assign a batch command output to Chef recipe attribute

Tags: ruby, chef-infra, cookbook

I have a windows command to check the directory which is updated recently .

```
for /f "delims=" %a in (' dir C:\Users\Username\cookbooks /ad /od /b ') do set "Last=%a";
echo %Last%;
```

I would like to assign output of above command to a Chef recipe attribute/cookbook attribute.

I did tried to directly execute above command in a batch resource and assign output but failed.
Is there a way to do so in Chef cookbook attribute ?

Answer (score 0):

you can run the a command as a part of the cookbook execution and assign the values to a node attributes using [`shell_out`](https://docs.chef.io/dsl_recipe.html#shell-out)

for instance, it will look something like

```rb
ruby_block 'foo' do
  block do
    cmd = "your command here"
    shell = Mixlib::ShellOut.new(cmd).run_command
    stdout = shell.stdout
    node.default['my_key'] = stdout
  end
end
```